# What's the easiest way to get around the split utility's file limit (676 files) on bash in MacOS

Tags: bash, split, macos-sierra

I am trying to split a 50GB file into 1MB chunks, but I am running into split's 676 file limit. What is the easiest way to circumvent this restriction?

Comment: What limit? What version of split are you using?

Answer (score 1):

From the split man page:

> `-a suffix_length
>         Use suffix_length letters to form the suffix of the file name.`
>
> `...`
>
> `If -a is not specified, two letters are used as the suffix.`

So the limit of 676 files is only appearing because with the default two-letter suffix, split can uniquely name at most `26 x 26 = 676` files. So use the `-a` flag to allow you to name more files.

You can take the base 26 logarithm of the number of files you need to create, and then round up to the next integer, to determine the number of letters you'll need for the suffix. In this case, using a suffix made of 4 letters will be enough to meet your needs (allowing for 456,976 unique files).

Comment: Thank you very much @MarkSetchell! :) To be honest I didn't know of it immediately myself, and was actually messing around trying to come up with a neat solution to recursively break the file into smaller chunks using multiple calls to split, thinking there really was a hard limit to how many files it could process. After I had the eureka moment, in hindsight it seemed obvious that I should have looked elsewhere for the cause of the apparent limit... 676 would be a strange number to limit a utility's processing capability to!